# Prove that $(a-d)^2+(b-c)^2\geq 1.6$ if $a^2+4b^2=4$ and $cd=4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, problem-solving

Let $a, b, c, d$ be real numbers. I need to prove this innocent inequality
$$
(a-d)^2+(b-c)^2\geq 1.6
$$
if $a^2+4b^2=4$ and $cd=4$.

I was told that there exist nice and sweet elementary solutions.

Comment: Can i ask where this is from?

Comment: Maybe it will help to think of this geometrically? You have an ellipse in $a,b$ space, and you need to prove that any circle centered on a certain hyperbola crossing the ellipse has radius larger than $1.6$.

Comment: a hint that just plain and direct AM-GM won't work(setting variables equal). http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a%5E2%2B4b%5E2%3D4%2C+cd%3D4%2C+a%5E2%3D4b%5E2%2C+c%3Dd%2C+x%3D%28a-d%29%5E2%2B%28b-c%29%5E2

Comment: @AmireBendjeddou this is from tutor's forum

Comment: @Norbert are you sure that the equality can hold? I haven't been able to stablish it.

Comment: I've checked numerically, it is correct

Comment: @AmireBendjeddou If I remember right, I saw this inequality long ago, when I was a schoolboy.

Comment: what I get the min is 1.7748, when b=.5814,c=1.672955. it is impossible to =1.6.

Comment: @chenbai So my empirically suggested bound $\frac{121-40\sqrt 6}{13}=1.7708\dots$ is quite good.

Comment: @AlexRavsky,Ya,I have to say I am surprise to see your answer so closed!nice work!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I remember it right, I saw this inequality long ago, when I was a schoolboy. Then I didn’t solve it. But now it seems the following for me.

Of course, the geometric approach is the first solution idea, :-) but it should be developed. Without loss of generality, it suffices to consider Quadrant I of the plane (the disposition in the Quadrant III is symmetric). 
[image]

We try to find the parallel lines separating the curves. The experimental evidence suggests to try 
$2a+3b=x$ and $2d+3c=y$  (see the picture).

The first line. In the coordinates $(a/2,b)$ the line is a tangent to the unit circle. It these coordinates the line has the equation  $4(a/2)+3b=x$. Therefore it is tangent to the circle at the point $(4,3)/\sqrt{4^2+3^2}=(4/5,3/5)$. Then $x=(4\cdot (4/5)+3\cdot (3/5))=5$.

The second line. $2d+3b\ge 2\sqrt{2d\cdot 3b}=4\sqrt 6=y$.

The squared distance between the lines is $\frac {(x-y)^2}{2^2+3^2}=1.77\dots>1.6$.

Comment: to get $1.6$ one need to consider tangent line to the ellipsis in the point $(2^{1/2},2^{-1/2})$.

Answer (score 5):

Using $a^2 + 4b^2 = 4$ and $cd = 4$, we have
\begin{align*}
 &(a - d)^2 + (b - c)^2 + \frac12(a^2 + 4b^2 - 4) - \frac{2\sqrt 2}{3}(cd - 4)\\[6pt]
 =\,& \frac16(3a - 2d)^2 + \frac13(3b - c)^2 + \frac13(d - c\sqrt 2)^2 + \frac{8\sqrt 2}{3} - 2 \\[6pt]
 \ge\, &\frac{8\sqrt 2}{3} - 2\\
 >\,& \frac85.
\end{align*}
We are done.

Answer (score 2):

it is supplementary to Alex's method which more like high school method:

The idea is same,we use two parallel lines to calculate. let slop is $k=-\tan{ \alpha}, 0<\alpha <\dfrac{\pi}{2}$,

the tangent line to ellipse $x^2+4y^2=4$ is :$y=kx+b_1 \to x^2+4(kx+b_1)^2=4, \Delta=0,\implies b_1^2=4k^2+1$

the tangent line to  Hyperbola $xy=4$ is:$y=kx+b \to x(kx+b)=4, \Delta=0,\implies k=-\dfrac{b^2}{4^2}$

$b_1=\sqrt{\dfrac{b^4}{64}+1},\cos{\alpha}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2{\alpha}}}=\dfrac{4^2}{\sqrt{b^4+4^4}}$

the distance between two lines is: $D=(b-b_1)\cos{\alpha}=\left(b-\sqrt{\dfrac{b^4}{64}+1}\right)\dfrac{4^2}{\sqrt{b^4+4^4}}=\dfrac{2(8b-\sqrt{b^4+64})}{\sqrt{b^4+4^4}}=\dfrac{2(64b^2-b^4-64)}{\sqrt{b^4+4^4}(b+\sqrt{b^4+64})}=\dfrac{2(960-(b^2-32^2)^2)}{\sqrt{b^4+4^4}(b+\sqrt{b^4+64})}$

the numerator is Parabola, the peak is at $b^2=32,b=4\sqrt{2}$

the denominator is mono increasing function, and it is lead by $b^4$, so it will cause the peak of $D$ move left strongly. The $D(b)$ has two zero points at about $b=1,8$, so the peak point should be around $3$ or $4$( it is guess).

$D(3)=1.3,D(4)=1.25 \implies D^2=1.69>1.6$  so we have at least one solution to show the square of distance of two points $(a,b),(c,d) >1.6 $

if we try $D(3.5)=1.76$, so if we set min is $1.7$,it is much hard to high school student.

Comment: I thought in this direction, trying to improve my answer, and I have obtained a problem to minimize something like $\frac {(\sqrt{4\alpha^2+\beta^2}-4\sqrt{\alpha\beta})^2}{\alpha^2+\beta^2}$. And I left this problem with the words that it maybe as hard as the initial.

Comment: If we cannot obtain the exact bound, we use supplementary methods helping us to do aright guess.

Answer (score 1):

If $a^2+4b^2=4$ , we have an ellipse with width $2$ and height $1$. Now, the set of points $cd=4$ describes a hyperbola which does not cross the ellipse. You need to prove that:
$$(a-d)^2 + (b-c)^2 \geq 1.6$$
This is equation for a circle centered around the point $(c,d)$ which lies on the hyperbola.
In other words, your problem is to prove that the hyperbola is always at least $1.6$ units away from the ellipse.

Therefore, it is enough to find the minimal distance between the functions:
$$f(x) = \frac{4}{x},\ \ g(x) = \sqrt{\frac{4 - x^2}{4}}$$
And to show that this is larger than $1.6$, i.e. find the minimum of:

$$\min_{x_1,x_2} \sqrt{\left(  \frac{4}{x_1} - \sqrt{\frac{4 - x_2^2}{4}} \right)^2 -(x_1-x_2)^2}$$
In the range $x_2\in[0,2]$, $x_1>0$.

Comment: why this function answers the question

Comment: Because it proves that $(a-d)^2 + (b-c)^2 \geq 1.6$

Comment: ok how do you make this reduction?

Comment: @Norbert - I added some more detail, hope this is more clear.

Comment: i don't think that this is elementary and of course it is not simple

Comment: The trick to is think of it geometrically, not just as a set of inequalities. It's a rather clever solution, actually :)

Comment: @Norbert - I'm sure there's an easier way to find the minimal distance, If I find it, i'll write it. Right now I still think the geometrical approach has a lot of potential.

Comment: @AHatThrowaway I've attacked this problem geometrically and got much farther then nbibus. In fact exact minumum is impossible to find since one will deal with cubic equation. The inequality in question is not the best possible

Comment: I think it should be emphasized that you're finding the minimal distance between _curves_ and not just _functions_.