# Find the minimum of $x^2+y^2+z^2$ under several constraints

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, maxima-minima

Let $x,y,z \in (-1;1)$ such that
$$13\left( {xy + yz + zx + 1} \right) + 14\left( {x + y + z + xyz} \right) = 0.$$
Find the minimum value of the following expression
$$P=x^2+y^2+z^2.$$

I guess the minimum value is $\frac{3}{4}$ and I will try to prove that prediction. From the conditions of the variables, I thought of trigonometry. However, it cannot be used due to the conditions
$$13\left( {xy + yz + zx + 1} \right) + 14\left( {x + y + z + xyz} \right) = 0.$$
I also thought of the $pqr$ method, but the variables are real numbers (which can be negative), so I couldn't implement the idea. Please provide some suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: Lion Heart $13\left( {xy + yz + zx + 1} \right) + 14\left( {x + y + z + xyz} \right) = 0.$

Comment: Did you mean to write $(-1,1)$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos. Sorry! (-1;1)

Comment: @Math_fun2006 The pqr method is applied to real numbers (including negative ones). So why couldn't you apply the idea?

Comment: @CalvinLin Simply let $a = x + 1, b = y + 1, c = z + 1$ to avoid negative and use pqr.

Comment: @RiverLi Thank you, this is a great idea. I have performed and obtained
$$14abc+2(a+b+c)=ab+bc+ca+4$$
But I don't know how to proceed with $$P=(a−1)^2+(b−1)^2+(c−1)^2$$
. Can you help me? Thank you!

Comment: @Math_fun2006 Although pqr works, it is not nice. I will give another proof.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Answer**: The minimum is $3/4$ when $x = y = z = -1/2$.

**Proof**:

WLOG, assume that $(y + 1/2)(z + 1/2)\ge 0$ (i.e. $y$ and $z$ are on the same side of $-1/2$; Pigeonhole Principle).
*Note*: Or note that $(x+1/2)(y+1/2)\cdot (y+1/2)(z+1/2) \cdot (z+1/2)(x+1/2) \ge 0$. So at least one of the three terms is non-nagative. WLOG, assume that $(y + 1/2)(z + 1/2)\ge 0$.

We have
\begin{align*}
 &x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - \frac34 + \frac29\cdot [13(xy + yz + zx + 1) + 14(x + y + z + xyz)]\\[6pt]
 ={}& \frac{28}{9}(x + 1)(y + 1/2)(z + 1/2) + \frac{1}{36}(6x + 4y + 4z + 7)^2 + \frac59(y-z)^2\\[6pt]
 \ge{}& 0.
\end{align*}

We are done.

Comment: Your solution is great. Thank you very much! I have a question about how to add just enough and combine it logically as mentioned above.

Comment: You can used the method of unknown coefficients. $L(x, \lambda) = f(x) + \lambda g(x)$. Then $\frac{\partial L}{\partial x} = 0$ at the minimizer. See more examples here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/449755/prove-that-a-d2b-c2-geq-1-6-if-a24b2-4-and-cd-4/4539078#4539078